# Is there a binary that I could install and run?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, macos

Some of my attempts researching how to get EOS up and running:

- there is no public testnet: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Testnet:-Public
- it takes a lot of memory to compile: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/1573
- here they've suggested Docker: https://old.reddit.com/r/EOSDev/comments/8nmlfu/is_there_a_vm_i_could_just_download_and_dont/

Is there a binary I could simply run?

- `brew install eos`
- `apt-get install eos`

You get the idea... **Easier to get stared = wider adoption.**

---

I'm terrible at solving build issues, that's why I'm working on the front-end, that's why it is easier for me to download 20GB VM rather than trying to configure everything. Right now giving Docker another shot: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart

Comment: Not sure if this is related but have you seen the jungle testnet? https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-Jungle-Testnet

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride look at the answer below - you are not the only one suggesting Crypto Lions...

Comment: Did you have a look at the Docker documentation on GitHub? Running it locally would be a simple "docker pull eosio/eos" and a "docker-compose up"

Comment: It actually works! I didn't expect to be that easy... Producing my own blocks. Now onto first smart contract deployment...

Comment: Maybe you should put your solution into an answer, so that people find it easier.

Comment: @TeeAttack42 done... Silly me, it was super easy!

Answer (score 3):

**I cannot believe it was that easy.**

My previous experience with Docker was terrible - error upon error, some configuration issues. I guess it was on the application level, not Docker level.

This time around - it just works! EOS running in 2 lines of code: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart

---

1. Pull the image from the repository:

`docker pull eosio/eos-dev`

2. And start the EOSIO node:

`sudo docker run --rm --name eosio -d -p 8888:8888 -p 9876:9876 -v /tmp/work:/work -v /tmp/eosio:/mnt/dev/data eosio/eos-dev /bin/bash -c "nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::wallet_api_plugin --plugin eosio::wallet_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin -d /mnt/dev/data --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:8888 --access-control-allow-origin=* --contracts-console"`

3. Check its working:

`sudo docker logs --tail 10 eosio`

Answer (score 0):

actually there has not yet had an official testnet actually as declare at developer portal there is community testnet that you can try http://dev.cryptolions.io

Comment: I've had a look... `need already installed EOS` - it seems like installing EOS is required, the only thing is a testnet... Ouch! Now I see, my question wasn't precise enough... I mixed two concepts - seamless install and testnet. So now I know about testnet!